# invalid perception_pcl repository for fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, perception-pcl, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The link on the wiki [page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/perception_pcl) seems not valid.

Can someone fix it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65886/invalid-perception_pcl-repository-for-fuerte/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which PCL version you are trying for ? Last friday June 21, fuerte was updated and issues related to pre PCL 1.6 versions were resolved. Hence, this should work fine.

You can install the ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-fuerte-unstable (sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-fuerte-unstable) package which adds pcl16 and pcl16_ros packages that track PCL 1.6.

The namespaces, filenames, and everything else have been changed from pcl to pcl16, so you need to make some minor changes to your code.
Like pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB becomes pcl16::PointCloudpcl16::PointXYZRGB. Doing it this way lets the two PCL versions coexist nicely.

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-06-25**:
I need to rebuild it from sources.

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-07-01**:
@devasena: Do you plan to enable access to the sources via "apt-get source" ?

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-07-01**:
No, but which PCL version you are trying to install ? " http://www.ros.org/wiki/perception_pcl " link that you are referring to is working fine and is valid.

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-07-01**:
I'm trying to install the source for fuerte. The command fails:\n$ svn co [http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl\n](http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl%5Cn)
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-07-02**:
The updated debs of ros-fuerte-pcl are available here : " http://50.28.27.175/repos/building/pool/main/r/ros-fuerte-pcl/ " You can download based on the ubuntu distro (lucid, precise or oneiric) you are using.

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-07-03**:
I would have preferred the release for the armhf architecture. Thanks for your effort anyway.